# Show duplicate values count in single row in single column based on id

Tags: sql

I have requrement where i have to show no of cptcodes applied on a patient of same provider and show the total amount of that cptcodes in next column.

I have tried to group the query based on provider id but did not get desired output.

Below is my result of table.

| InvoiceId | ProviderId | PatientId | CPTCode1 | CPTPrize1 | Freqency | CPTCode2 | CPTPrize2 | Freqency2 | BillingMonth | BillingYear | TotalMinutes | TotalAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99FA9690-119E-4CC6-988E-14BEA96A6791 | 7AEE31CB-026B-42C1-98D5-32E0AD55BF88 | F1C26E5B-A43E-408A-BADC-5C5FFC33F1F1 | 99457 | 50.00 | 1 | 99458 | 79.00 | 4 | 10 | 2023 | 138 | 366.00 |
| F2262C6B-9A82-466B-B4AB-2D9A950B38A2 | EC417BB8-1B75-41F0-9314-F276AB25F7FA | 29BA2856-7343-433F-B6D0-19FB7343C2EB | 99457 | 50.00 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 10 | 2023 | 30 | 50.00 |
| C2A87579-87AA-47F0-828B-5F9601A0F3CC | 7AEE31CB-026B-42C1-98D5-32E0AD55BF88 | C2D7BD2E-6A44-406A-89CE-A36733BE0FB7 | 99457 | 50.00 | 1 | 99458 | 79.00 | 1 | 10 | 2023 | 50 | 129.00 |
| 68CB33AE-761D-4530-8C40-AAA1C2D83788 | 7AEE31CB-026B-42C1-98D5-32E0AD55BF88 | 6FCBFDA3-5C77-47AE-B499-5019AD37E2D9 | 99457 | 50.00 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 10 | 2023 | 21 | 50.00 |
| F2DD2DBA-3869-434C-86E4-AE35F64F17EC | EC417BB8-1B75-41F0-9314-F276AB25F7FA | FA3E2AF0-26FD-4932-BD62-1B107EFBAF0D | 99457 | 50.00 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 10 | 2023 | 33 | 50.00 |
| 2C90ACDF-E4EE-4052-B306-CDBBA15D29FC | B8B5A939-330D-4F8B-A171-624BB228B0A0 | 17328880-D85B-4B19-937A-78F336583BCB | 99457 | 50.00 | 1 | 99458 | 79.00 | 1 | 10 | 2023 | 40 | 129.00 |

Above is the result of my tblinvoice table

I want to display result like below based on above result
it should fetch single providerid and based on patientid it should count the cptcode ie. how many times the same cptcode is applied
amount will be calculated based on cptcode cound ie. 99457 amount is 50 then 50*3=150 and 99458 amount is 79 then 79*2 158 then total amount
will be 308, just like below I have provided example
I want result like below.

| ProviderId | Month | CPTCode | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7AEE31CB-026B-42C1-98D5-32E0AD55BF88 | October | 99457(3),99458(2) | 308 |

Comment: You have tagged both SQL server and oracle... Which is it?

Comment: And where is your query?

Comment: sql server SELECT
    ProviderId,
    CONCAT(MONTHNAME(CONCAT(BillingYear, '-', BillingMonth, '-01')),' ',BillingYear) AS Month,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(CPTCode1, '(', COALESCE(COUNT(CPTCode1), 0), ')'), ',',
                CONCAT(CPTCode2, '(', COALESCE(COUNT(CPTCode2), 0), ')')) AS CPTCode,
    SUM(
        (COALESCE(COUNT(CPTCode1), 0) * CPTPrize1) +
        (COALESCE(COUNT(CPTCode2), 0) * CPTPrize2)
    ) AS Amount
FROM tblinvoice
GROUP BY ProviderId, BillingMonth, BillingYear;

Comment: [edit] into your question

Comment: Looks like a comma-delimited result here with a (windowed) `COUNT`.

Comment: This would be easier if you normalised your data too. What would happen if you needed 3 different CPT values? Can a `CPTCode2` contain 2, or more, different values?

Comment: if there is any third type of cptcode then it will append in the same row and their amount will be added.       eg.
ProviderId                Month              CPTCode                     Amount                

7AEE31CB-026B-42C1-98D5-32E0AD55BF88     October         99453, 99457(3),99458(2)                308                                                  
in above example cptcode 99453 will added and their amount too

Comment: Blargh... Definitely fix your design.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned my desired format, can you please check the above?

ProviderId                                                            Month              CPTCode                     Amount                

7AEE31CB-026B-42C1-98D5-32E0AD55BF88     October          99457(3),99458(2)                308

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags, as they weren't addressed. SQL Server uses T-SQL, not PL/SQL (which is used by Oracle). When you [edit] your question to provide your attempt(s), don't forget to (re)add the correct tags.

Comment: But you shouldn't have columns like `CPTCode1` and `CPTCode2`, you should just have a `CPTCode` column and one row per value.

Comment: thanks for formatting the question, but my solution is still not visible, which is the main reason for prompting the above question in this forum.
i have divided the CPT codes based on requirements some patient has single cptcode and some can have multiple cptcodes like 99457,99458

Comment: [so] isn't a forum, it's a Q&A site. It does not act like a forum and trying to use it like one will result in a poor experience. As for your solution, no one has posted one. We don't know what product you are using; we can't post an answer when we don't know what dialect of SQL we should be using. And, again, please [edit] your question to include *your* attempts.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, sample data like 1, 2 ,3 are so much easier than F2262C6B-9A82-466B-B4AB-2D9A95WB38A2, F2242C6B-9A82-466B-B4AB-2D9A950B38A2F2262C6B-9A82-4656B-B4AB-2D9A950B38A2.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in the comments (several times), you really need to normalise your design. If you do that, this is *much* easier. You should have 1 CPTCode, etc, column, not 2. Then you have 1 row per value of CPTCode.

This solution *assumes* SQL Server, as it was initially tagged; if you aren't using that then this won't work and you **need** to fix your question (you've been asked many times).

Firstly the solution normalises the data, by unpivoting the data with a table `VALUES` construct. Then it aggregates the data by CPT Code and Provider ID.

Then you can aggregate the data from the aggregation and concatenate to the `COUNT` and CPT Code to get your desired value for `CPTCode`. I don't bother "Englishing" `10` to October (that feels like a presentation layer problem).

This gives the following solution (with a CTE to create the sample data, as we lack DDL and DML):

```sql
--Create sample data
WITH YourData (InvoiceId,ProviderId,PatientId,CPTCode1,CPTPrize1,Freqency,CPTCode2,CPTPrize2,Freqency2,BillingMonth,BillingYear,TotalMinutes,TotalAmount) AS (
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,InvoiceId),
           TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,ProviderId),
           TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,PatientId),
           TRY_CONVERT(int,CPTCode1),
           TRY_CONVERT(decimal(6,2),CPTPrize1),
           TRY_CONVERT(int,Freqency), --Should this be Frequency? Why not Frequency1?
           TRY_CONVERT(int,CPTCode2),
           TRY_CONVERT(decimal(6,2),CPTPrize2),
           TRY_CONVERT(int,Freqency2), --Should this be Frequency2?
           TRY_CONVERT(int,BillingMonth),
           TRY_CONVERT(int,BillingYear),
           TRY_CONVERT(int,TotalMinutes),
           TRY_CONVERT(decimal(6,2),CPTPrize2)
    FROM (VALUES('99FA9690-119E-4CC6-988E-14BEA96A6791','7AEE31CB-026B-42C1-98D5-32E0AD55BF88','F1C26E5B-A43E-408A-BADC-5C5FFC33F1F1','99457','50.00','1','99458','79.00','4','10','2023','138','366.00'),
                ('F2262C6B-9A82-466B-B4AB-2D9A950B38A2','EC417BB8-1B75-41F0-9314-F276AB25F7FA','29BA2856-7343-433F-B6D0-19FB7343C2EB','99457','50.00','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','10','2023','30','50.00'),
                ('C2A87579-87AA-47F0-828B-5F9601A0F3CC','7AEE31CB-026B-42C1-98D5-32E0AD55BF88','C2D7BD2E-6A44-406A-89CE-A36733BE0FB7','99457','50.00','1','99458','79.00','1','10','2023','50','129.00'),
                ('68CB33AE-761D-4530-8C40-AAA1C2D83788','7AEE31CB-026B-42C1-98D5-32E0AD55BF88','6FCBFDA3-5C77-47AE-B499-5019AD37E2D9','99457','50.00','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','10','2023','21','50.00'),
                ('F2DD2DBA-3869-434C-86E4-AE35F64F17EC','EC417BB8-1B75-41F0-9314-F276AB25F7FA','FA3E2AF0-26FD-4932-BD62-1B107EFBAF0D','99457','50.00','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','10','2023','33','50.00'),
                ('2C90ACDF-E4EE-4052-B306-CDBBA15D29FC','B8B5A939-330D-4F8B-A171-624BB228B0A0','17328880-D85B-4B19-937A-78F336583BCB','99457','50.00','1','99458','79.00','1','10','2023','40','129.00'))V(InvoiceId,ProviderId,PatientId,CPTCode1,CPTPrize1,Freqency,CPTCode2,CPTPrize2,Freqency2,BillingMonth,BillingYear,TotalMinutes,TotalAmount)),
--The Solution
/*WITH */Aggregates AS(
    SELECT YD.ProviderId,
           V.CPTCode,
           YD.BillingMonth,
           COUNT(V.CPTCode) AS CodeCount,
           SUM(V.CPTPrice) AS CPTPrice
    FROM YourData YD
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CPTCode1,CPTPrize1,Freqency),
                            (CPTCode2,CPTPrize2,Freqency2))V(CPTCode,CPTPrice,Frequency)
    WHERE V.CPTCode IS NOT NULL
      AND YD.ProviderId = '7aee31cb-026b-42c1-98d5-32e0ad55bf88'
    GROUP BY YD.ProviderId,
             V.CPTCode,
             YD.BillingMonth)
SELECT A.ProviderId,
       A.BillingMonth AS [Month],
       STRING_AGG(CONCAT(A.CPTCode,'(',A.CodeCount,')'),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.CPTCode) AS CPTCode,
       SUM(A.CPTPrice) AS Amount
FROM Aggregates A
GROUP BY A.ProviderId,
         A.BillingMonth;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/34mVooPw)